# Entity Framework Insertion using Code First With Confirmation

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I use this function for inserting data with `DetailsView` and it works fine

```
public Void InsertIntoTblItem(TblItem tblItem)
{
    orderDBContext.TblItem.Add(tblItem);
    orderDBContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

But I want to know is how to handle confirmation string.

```
public string InsertIntoTblItem(TblItem tblItem)
{
    if (orderDBContext.TblItem.Where(x => x.ID == tblItem.ID) == null)
    {
        orderDBContext.TblItem.Add(tblItem);
        orderDBContext.SaveChanges();
        return "New Item Saved";
    }

    return "Item Not Saved";
}
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

the return value of [SaveChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges(v=vs.103).aspx) is the number of objects updated in the context, So you can use it to ensure data has been saved or not:

```
int returnValue =  orderDBContext.SaveChanges();
return returnValue > 0 ? "New Item Saved" : "Item Not Saved";
```

Comment: Thanks
But how to receive and display confirmation on web form using DetailsView With ObjectDataSource